# are astronomy and astrology apt names for their concepts?

Tags: etymology

Or be switching them be correct, since the original assignment was a historical convention? Or do neither suffix convey enough meaning; we can create 'bionomy' if 'biology' was already taken?

Comment: By now they're proper and proprietary names. _Astrology_ is what _astrologers_ do, and _astronomy_ is what _astronomers_ do. Both have to do with stars, but in completely different ways and using completely different concepts of _star_ -- just as different as the Hollywood concept of _star_. Astronomers don't like to be called astrologers, and vice versa.

Comment: Clear as crystal.

Comment: _All_ words are conventional. The history of words is often interesting, but utterly unreliable in determining the current meaning. You are welcome to use words in unconventional ways (e.g. swapping two established words), but you risk being misunderstood if you do so.

Comment: @Colin [Prof Pullum](http://news.ucsc.edu/2002/04/107.html) wouldn't welcome you.

Comment: Another, arguably better, word for astrology is astromancy. "divination by stars".

Comment: Except, @Neil, that in Western Ptolemaic astrology the _stars_ are quite irrelevant. Rather, the positions of sun, moon, and planets along the ecliptic are reckoned in terms of angular distance from the equinoctial points where the ecliptic and celestial equator intersect. The _sign_ of Aries is named after the visible constellation Aries but is operationally defined as the first thirty degrees east of the vernal equinoctial point, which by now (thanks to precession since Ptolemy's time) corresponds more closely to the visible constellation Pisces.

Comment: Well I only said it was better, not perfect :) Anyway, for the ancient Greeks, the planets were stars. Not sure when that way of thinking ended.

Comment: Right you are. Ptolemy refers to Saturn as ὁ . . . τοῦ Κρόνου ἀστὴρ (the star of Kronos) @ _Tetrabiblos_  2.9.5.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't get your comment. I agree with everything Pullum is reported as saying in that review.

Comment: @Colin Fine: You are welcome to swap "It", "is" and "I" for "It's" and "me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've often wondered the same thing. I expect *astronomy* was coined to differentiate the scientific study of heavenly bodies from the pseudoscience of predicting fortunes from them. Had *astrology* never existed as a term, it seems like a likely candidate as the term for what we know as astronomy.

These kind of etymologies are never going to be quite right, of course—*physicists* and *physicians* have little to do with each other, but the words come from the same root.

Another question about the etymology of *astronomy*. Given that the suffix *-nomy* refers to systems and rules, it seems like the term should really refer to the rules that govern the heavenly bodies (compare to *economy* and *taxonomy*), rather than the study of those rules and the bodies. Why isn't the field of study called *astronomics* (like *economics*)?

Answer (score 1):

*Astronomy* is a science which involves studying everything outside our planet earth, looking through telescopes, studies and research etc. On the other hand *Astrology* deals with the positioning of planets and stars and their effect on humans and events (astrology is not a science but a *belief* that stars and planets effect human lives). Hope this helps. Ciao:)

Comment: Astonomy is indeed a science. Astrology, like numerology, is for the intellectually-challenged >;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the etymology of the  terms, it appears that *astrology* was used since the beginning  with a scientific meaning, while *astrology* which developed  later, was used to refer to both astronomy (natural astrology) and astrology ( judicial astrology). The later and current meanings of these two terms appear to reflect their original definition and evolution trough the centuries.

[astronomy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Astronomy&searchmode=none) (n.)

> c.1200, from Old French astrenomie, from Latin astronomia, from Greek astronomia, literally **"star arrangement," from astron "star" (see astro-) + nomos "arranging, regulating," related to nemein "to deal out" (see numismatic)**. Used earlier than astrology and originally including it.
> Þer wes moni god clarc to lokien in þan leofte, to lokien i þan steorren nehʒe and feorren. þe craft is ihate Astronomie. [Layamon, "The Brut," c.1200]

[astrology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Astronomy&searchmode=none) (n.)

> late 14c., from Latin astrologia "astronomy, the science of the heavenly bodies," from **Greek astrologia "telling of the stars,**" from astron "star" (see astro-) + -logia "treating of" (see -logy).
>
> Originally identical with astronomy, it had also a special sense of "practical astronomy, astronomy applied to prediction of events." **This was divided into natural astrology "the calculation and foretelling of natural phenomenon" (tides, eclipses, etc.), and judicial astrology "the art of judging occult influences of stars on human affairs" (also known as astromancy, 1650s)**. Differentiation between astrology and astronomy began late 1400s and **by 17c. this word was limited to "reading influences of the stars and their effects on human destiny."**